# How to autofill webform from GET vars?

Tags: entities, webforms, ajax

I need to make a form that autofills itself with some values that I give from the GET or POST params

I have an emailing that is personalized for each user so when they click on a link or a submit form they will view that webform autorefilled with their data

I'm using Drupal 6.19 and Webform 6.x-3.4

Comment: Please mention your Webform and Drupal version.

Answer (score 10):

Webform has GET support built-in, see: [Setting Default Values from the URL](http://drupal.org/node/296453#webform-url-default).

For POST you have access to `%post[key]` or you can retrieve `$_POST` and set your values using [`hook_form_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7).

> Webform allows several special values to be used as defaults when
>   configuring a component. The special placeholders are commonly called
>   tokens. The tokens Webform supports include:
>   %username
>   %useremail
>   %site
>   %date
>   %server[key]
>   %session[key]
>   %get[key]
>   %post[key]
>   %request[key]
>   %profile[key]

[Working with Default Values](http://drupal.org/node/296453)

Answer (score 1):

The [prepopulate](http://drupal.org/project/prepopulate) module does it for GET arguments.